# How can I create customized shapes in CSS react.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, css

I'm building a Landing Page in react.js and I want to create a custom shape similar to this image **{see below}**. As of now I have created some simple shapes and now I want to achieve new level in css by creating this shape. Please help me.
Here I am also sharing SVG of this image [SVG link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VzzUDQ1XA98s34my_Glfl0a2rU6OjAvQ/view?usp=sharing)
here is png format as well.
[image: referenced]

Comment: you have the SVG so you are done, no?

Comment: Isn't it possible to do the same without using svg? For eg. When we create a hexagonal we don't use svg then why use svg for that? Is that mean css has some limitations?

Comment: hexagone is an easy shape :) ... And CSS is not limited but it's not a drawing tool ... we can do some shapes not any shapes. That's why we have SVG and canvas ... trying this with pure CSS will give you headaches :p

Comment: Oh I see :-) Thanks a lot! Ahh.. just one more thing. Do Stripe and slack type website also use svg? They also have some custom shapes in background.

Comment: it depends on the shape but I would say yes if it's something like you are showing ... you can always verify using dev tools

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

For doing such complex shapes I would recommend using some drawing tool like Photoshop or Illustrator, then you export as SVG and use it.